# Creating Detail From An Image

Tags: modifiers

I've been creating some Helmets for my game, I wanted to add a little bit of character to the helmets, I'm going to try and design some of my own symbols / designs but I don't have any clue what the best way about using an image to create detail on an object ( protruding into the helmet ). My plan is to put a symbol around the "trim" of the helmet. I started to just use the cut tool but I quickly realized it wouldn't come out exactly how my design was, so I figured there has got to be a way quicker way to go about it.[image][image] I searched around but I guess my wording isn't correct, I don't truly know how to explain in depth what I want that well. My english isn't the best.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want the emblem to be raised up on the surface of the helmet like the cheek-guard of this one:
https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2a/83/b6/2a83b6dad8b9f28b7b2f86992e438e2d.jpg This tutorial should help you if you want to keep the emblem separate from the helmet. https://youtu.be/rcwdLbcjUT0?t=17m53s here's the link for earlier in the video when he talks about constructing the spider:
https://youtu.be/rcwdLbcjUT0?t=2m41s

Comment: Something [like this?](https://www.swordsdirect.com/viking-helmet.jpg) ..

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way:

- You can try to convert your picture in Illustrator, then import as a SVG, then convert curve to mesh. Give it thickness with an extrusion, then use the *Remesh* modifier to give it a good topology. Modifier settings: disable *Remove Disconnected Pieces*, *Mode* : Sharp, *Octree Depth* : 8, *Scale* : 0.3, *Sharpness* : 1  .
- If the result is too messy, recreate your ornemental shape from scratch with your model as a *Background Image*.
- Give your ornement mesh a thickness with two successive extrusions on the Z axis. The first extrusion must be thin as you'll later use a *Subdivision Surface* modifier.
- Create a plane, subdivide it to make a grid.
- Give your ornement a *Surface Deform* modifier, choose the grid as the *Target* and click *Bind*.
- Give your grid a *Shrinkwrap* modifier and choose the helmet as your *Target*. Now your ornement should stick to the helmet. Play with the Shrinkwrap *Offset* if necessary.
- Give your ornement a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to smooth the shape, also, click on *Shading* > *Smooth* on the left menu of your 3D view (activated with *T*).

When you have finished you can choose to Bake this helmet in order to fake the ornement in the Material with a Normal map.

[image]